# Is there a way to randomly add or subtract two specific numbers or more to an array of values?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am supposed to make a function that accepts an integer array as an input, and then randomly modify each value within the array by either -38 or 55, specifically. However, I'm not sure how to randomly choose whether a number will get deducted by -38 or added by 55, and how to go about this process.

I tried making an if statement within my function, stating that if a function is even (array[i] % 2), then deduct by -38, and if the number is odd (else statement), add by 55. While this may work, it's not the right way to answer this question, because what if I wanted to add an even number by 55? Or vice versa with an odd number with subtracting 38?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int output(int array[]){

    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
      cout << array[i] << " ";
    }

}

int offset(int array[]){

  for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  int myrand = rand();
  if (myrand % 2 == 0){
  array[j] = array[j] - 38;
  }
  else{
  array[j] = array[j] + 55;
  }
  }


}

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
   int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   cout << "Original: ";
   output(array);
   offset(array);

    return 0;
}
```

If the value within an array is 5, it should have the possibility of being 10 or 0, and so forth with any numbers.

Comment: Do you know how to do anything randomly? Do you know how to generate a random number, or a random boolean value?

Comment: Well, if the element is even deduct 38 or odd add 55 is hardly random. (unless the elements of the array are random). While it isn't bad, you could do just as well generating a random number, storing it, iterating over the bits and doing even/odd based on the 1/0. (and that reduces repeated calls to `rand`). There are a huge number of possibilities. Try several, see if you find one that is reasonably efficient and produces a reasonable distribution.

Comment: @Beta I know how to use the rand function, but only how to randomly generate a number within a specific range, such as doing rand() % 100, which will produce a random number between 0-99. I am not sure how to tie that into this problem though.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have only started to learn arrays, and so I don't know how to iterate over the bots and do even/odd based on the bits within my code. I am still stuck on how exactly to approach this problem, even though there might be a multitude of ways to go about it.

Comment: OK, that gives us something to shoot at. You must know the number of elements in the array to begin with. Your `for` loop is fine so long as you only have 5 elements. Within the loop, in its basic form, you could do `for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) { int myrand = rand(); if (myrand % 2 == 0) array[j] = array[j] - 38; else array[j] = array[j] + 55; }` You can use `-=` and `+=` for shorthand, e.g. `array[j] -= 38;`, etc... Give it a shot and let us know if you hare still stuck.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I just updated my code in the post; however, the code is not compiling. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: For starters look carefully at your error messages. They are probably telling you `cout` cannot be found and that `rand` and `srand` cannot be found. You are missing `#included <iostream>` and `#include <cstdlib>` for starters. Also you should move `srand(time(NULL));` into `main()` so it is only called once.

Comment: Also note, C++ has its own further refined random number generation scheme, e.g. [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) . Tip, bookmark [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) which is probably the best C++ internet reference. It will take a little white to figure out all that is there, a good place to start is the list of [C++ Standard Library headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) and browse from there. The Search is good too.

Comment: Ok, I just updated my code, but I am still getting an error? @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Do you *understand* the code that @DavidC.Rankin gave you? If not, then don't try to get it to work; try something simpler.

Comment: @Beta From my understanding, the code he gave me is that, he assigned the rand function to a variable, and then made an if statement block with this rand statement; if the number generated by the rand function is even, then subtract 38 from the array index value that the loop generates. But if it is odd, add 55.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get you started and then you can go from there. When beginning to learn any programming language, (or any language for that matter), you start with a large amount of what makes up the language, what are the words and what are the rules for putting them together. For a programming language that is its "syntax". Every language has its own. You begin learning the syntax with minimal examples that make use of the basic types and progress from there.

With a compiled language, you add to that, how you translate the collection of proper syntax in a file into a machine readable executable. How you compile the source code into an executable.

At this point, the most important thing you can do is make friends with your compiler and listen to what it is telling you. You do this most effectively by enabling compiler warnings so your compiler will point out for you the line (and in many cases the character in the line) that it finds troubling. The rule is

> "Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code
>   until it *compiles cleanly without warning*."

To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your `gcc/clang` compile string. For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windows), use `/W3`. There are always additional warnings you can add, but this will provide a thorough set that if you follow the rule will save you hours of time debugging.

With that as background, let's look at what you are trying to do. First, you have tagged your Question as C++. I provided you in the comment above a place to start to determine what basic header files were needed in your proposed code. [C++ Standard Library headers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header). Checking you will find that C++ provides an implementation of `time.h` as the header `ctime` (all of the standard C headers are generally named `c......`). So here, based on what you included in your code, you would need, at minimum,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
```

While you can use `5` in your code, you want to avoid hard-coding numbers (unless required by the standard library function being used, such as the C `scanf` *field-width* modifier, which does not allow a named constant or variable in that case). Hard-coding numbers is called using *magic-numbers* and is best avoided.

When you declare and initialize an array, you can declared the array with an empty `[]` (which would normally be an incomplete type), but by virtue of providing a braced-initializer, the compiler uses the number of elements provided to size the array at compile time. You can then determine the number of elements with the array by dividing the `sizeof array` by the `sizeof (an_element)`. You can simply derefernce the array to obtain the first element, so you will see it written as follows:

```
int main (void) {

    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int nelem = sizeof array / sizeof *array;   /* number of elements */
    ...
```

Now when passing basic-type arrays to a function, you also need to pass the number of elements as well. Why? When an array is passed as a parameter (actually on any access, subject to limited exceptions), an array is converted to a pointer to the first element. If you tried to use the `sizeof array / sizeof (an_element)` within a function after passing the array as a parameter, you would end up with `sizeof (a_pointer) / sizeof (an_element)` which is certainly not going to work.

So for example, in your `output()` function, to pass the number of elements along with the array, you would need:

```
void output (int array[], int nelem)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nelem; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

The same would apply equally to your `offset()` function:

```
void offset (int array[], int nelem)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < nelem; j++) {
        int myrand = rand();
        if (myrand % 2 == 0) {
            array[j] = array[j] - 38;
        }
        else{
            array[j] = array[j] + 55;
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** the return `type` for each function has been changed to `void` rather than `int`. Neither function need provide an indication of success/failure and neither is returning a value that is being used back in the calling function, `main()` here. In each case you are simply printing the elements of the array, or updating their values in-place.)

The remainder for your first attempt is simply to output the array before applying the offset, and then again afterwards. Your `main()` could be:

```
int main (void) {

    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int nelem = sizeof array / sizeof *array;   /* number of elements */

    srand (time(NULL));     /* seed random number generator */

    cout << "Original: ";   /* output original array */
    output (array, nelem);

    offset (array, nelem);  /* apply offset to array */

    cout << "Updated : ";   /* output original array */
    output (array, nelem);

    return 0;
}
```

If you put all the pieces together, and compile with warnings enabled, will find your code compiles without warning and produces a working executable.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/randaddtoarray
Original: 1 2 3 4 5
Updated : 56 57 58 -34 -33
```

If you run it multiple times you will probably see that you don't always have an even number of odd or even random numbers. That is the nature of random numbers.

As mentioned in the comments, there are many many ways to approach developing a random scheme for applying your `-38` or `+55`. Take some time and research the different methods and try implementing them and see how your results change. You will probably want to add more than 5 values to your array to be able to draw any kind of distribution conclusion. Five values is really not enough to provide any type of clear comparison.

Let me know if you have further problem.